# Ajax, how to get data from an HTML form

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms

I'm driving myself crazy with Ajax at the moment, there is something that im not getting.

I want a user to input their password, then their new password twice, but i want to use Ajax to send that data to a PHP script to check it and to store the new password in the database if needed.

I just don't understand how to get the data from the HTML form to the Ajax script. Everywhere i look on the internet the information just seems to confuse me that little but more, this always seems to be the case when trying to find help with Java related product i feel.

So heres teh Ajax:

```
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
        //document.myForm.time.value = ajaxRequest.responseText;
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}

var queryString = "?oldpass=" + oldpass + "&newpass=" + newpass + "&newpassretype="     + newpassretype;

ajaxRequest.open("post", "serverTime.php", true);
ajaxRequest.send(queryString); //Would use this to send post data (passwords) to the script
```

I have missed out all the broswer specific stuff because im sure you've seen it all before.

```
<form>
<input type="password" name="oldpass" id="oldpass" />
<input type="password" name="newpass" id="newpass" />
<input type="password" name="newpassretype" id="newpassretype" />
<input type="submit" onclick="ajaxFunction('oldpass', 'newpass', 'newpassretype')" name="button2" id="button2" value="Change Password" />
<div id="txtHint"></div></form>
```

I think i miss something here, but i haven't got a clue what it is! ANy ideas?

thanks for your time and i hope this isn't something silly.

Comment: JavaScript is "Java related" in the same way that pie is "photocopier related". (Actually I guess it's more like how a photocopier is "pie related" :-)

Comment: You missed that the English word "I" is rendered in all-capitals.

Comment: It's more like how a carpet is "car related".

Comment: Yes OK @Quentin - I'm wit-challenged :-)

Comment: Okay so i missed out the word script..... Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change this one line and it will work...

```
var queryString = "?oldpass=" + document.forms[0]["oldpass"].value +
    "&newpass=" + document.forms[0]["newpass"].value +
    "&newpassretype=" + document.forms[0]["newpassretype"].value;
```

2 things though...

1. You're passing the password **and** the confirmation in the URL.  That's not needed as you should check that they're the same at client side, rather than send them to be checked at server side.
2. You shouldn't send password information in a URL as it's the easiest thing in the world to capture.

Comment: *ReferenceError: $ is not defined* (And even if it was, you need to encode the data to make it safe for URIs).

Comment: Sorry - been looking at jQuery questions all afternoon and answered this one incorrectly.  I'll update for non-jQuery.  Thanks :)

Comment: Okay, but now i don't get any output from the php file, this is just a script that just echo's some text. Any ideas?

Comment: MD5 isn't encryption and if you do that everywhere then you are just changing what the client has to send to the server, so an attacker can still capture it and send that to the server herself. If you want security, use SSL (and keep data out of query strings where it is more likely to get logged or stored in history).

Comment: Im not worried about security at the moment, i understand all that. Just want the script to work!

Comment: In that case the above will do what you asked.

Answer (score 1):

You have hard coded strings that you are passing to `ajaxFunction`, you need to use DOM to access the form fields and get their values. You also need to run `encodeURIComponent` over them to make them safe to drop into the query string.